# Django: How To Call ModelAdmin.save_model()

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin

I need to write a method in my ModelAdmin class that calls ModelAdmin.save_model(), without the user actually clicking on save.

(The reason I want to do this is that I set up some custom buttons in my Django Admin object view. They work but any modified form data is lost, I want to save the data in the form before running the actions connected to the button.)

Here's my code:

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Object


class ObjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def action_method(self, request, object):
        self.save_model(request=request, obj=object, form=self.form, change=True)

admin.site.register(Object, ObjectAdmin)
```

This doesn't raise any errors but also doesn't save my data.

I'm guessing my problem might be to do with the form.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

```
class AuthorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        # Code Logic
        obj.save()
```

[Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model)

Comment: Thanks but this isn't what I am trying to do. I want to be able to call the save_model method from another method.